# par() from .ini file unexpected behaviour

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to get a value (iatDistribution) from the .ini file to run in the simulation but it will not work.

I have tried hard-coding a value in and it works. But using the variable it won't work.

**`.cc`** File

```
void PacketGen::initialize()
{
    int seqno = 0;
    int txId = getParentModule()->par("nodeId");
    int messageSize = par("messageSize");
    double distro = par("iatDistribution");

    scheduleAt(simTime(), new cMessage); //sends the initial message!
}

void PacketGen::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    appMessage* message = createMessage();
    send(message, "out0");
    scheduleAt((distro + simTime()), msg);
}
```

**`.ini`** File

```
#Gen & Sink
simulation.TXNode[*].packGen.messageSize = 64
simulation.TXNode[*].packGen.iatDistribution = 0.1
```

**`packGen.ned`** file

```
simple PacketGen
{
    parameters:
        int messageSize;
        double iatDistribution;

    gates:
        output out0;
}
```

When a value like `0.1` replaces `distro` in the `scheduleAt((distro + simTime()), msg);` line, the simulation time increases but when trying to use the `distro` variable it does not.

Answer (score 1):

In `initialize()` you assigned the value of parameter `iatDistribution` into **local variable** `distro`. And probably you have declared variable `distro` as a member of `PacketGen` class.
Therefore change the line:

```
double distro = par("iatDistribution");
```

into:

```
distro = par("iatDistribution");
```